# sql, effecting different rows with different buttons

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

i have a project looks like this.
[image]

i want to view picture then want to write something about this picture. the "gönder" button should effect the right above picture. i want to add these to docYorum in my sql table (i placed it below), then i want to delete if i write my things about this picture.

my sql table:
[image]

my codes:

rontgenDoc.php

```
<?php
define('TITLE', 'Requests');
define('PAGE', 'rontgenDoc');
include('includes/header.php'); 
include('../dbConnection.php');
session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION['is_adminlogin'])){
  $aEmail = $_SESSION['aEmail'];
 } else {
  echo "<script> location.href='login.php'; </script>";
 }
?>
<div class="col-sm-4 mb-5">
  <!-- Main Content area start Middle -->
  <?php 
 $sql = "SELECT file_name, hastaAdi, request, requestDetail FROM images";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);
 if($result->num_rows > 0){
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
   echo '<div class="card mt-5 mx-5">';
   echo '<div class="card-header">';
   echo 'Hasta Adı : '. $row['hastaAdi'];
   echo '</div>';
   echo '<div class="card-body">';
   echo '<h5 class="card-title">Request Info : ' . $row['request'] . '</h5>';
   echo '<p class="card-text">Açıklama: ' . $row['requestDetail'] . '</p>';
   echo '<p class="card-text">Röntgen Görseli: <img id="myImg" width="100" height="100" src="../patient/uploads/' . $row['file_name'] . '"></p>';
   echo '<div class="float-right">';
   echo '<form action="" method="POST"> <input type="hidden" name="id" value='. $row["hastaAdi"] .'><input type="submit" class="btn btn-info mr-3" name="view" value="View"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" name="close" value="Close"></form>';
   echo '</div>' ;
   echo '</div>' ;
   echo'</div>';
   $num = 12;
   echo '
   <form action="docYorum.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-12 mt-5">
      <form class="mx-10" action="" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="docYorum">Doktor Değerlendirmesi</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="docYorum" placeholder="Doctor Yorumu" name="docYorum" value="'.$row['id'].'">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit">Gönder</button>
  </form>
   
   ';
  }
 } else {
  echo '<div class="alert alert-info mt-5 col-sm-6" role="alert">
  <h4 class="alert-heading">Well done!</h4>
  <p>Aww yeah, you successfully assigned all Requests.</p>
  <hr>
  <h5 class="mb-0">No Pending Requests</h5>
</div>';
 }
?>
<?php
include('includes/footer.php'); 
$conn->close();
?>
```

docYorum.php:

```
<?php
// Include the database configuration file
include('dbConnection.php');
session_start();
$r=session_id();
$statusMsg = '';
$sql = "SELECT file_name FROM images";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$docYorum = $_REQUEST['docYorum'];
if($result->num_rows > 0){
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]) ){
        $fileName=$row["file_name"];
        $insert = $conn->query("UPDATE images SET docYorum='$docYorum' WHERE id='..'");

 }
}
}

            

// Display status message
echo $statusMsg;
?>
<script>console.log(<?php echo $sql?>)</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of your code?

Comment: @HanisHapsa sorry i forgat to add most important part. added

Comment: Keep in mind that the input is not escaped(`$docYorum`) this means your code is vulnerable to sql injections!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this form in rontgenDoc.php should be like

```
<form action="docYorum.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-12 mt-5">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="docYorum">Doktor Değerlendirmesi</label>
          <input type="text" name="id" hidden value="'.$row['id'].'">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="docYorum" placeholder="Doctor Yorumu" name="docYorum" value="">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit">Gönder</button>
   </div>       
</form>
```

docYorum.php should be like

```
<?php
// Include the database configuration file
include('dbConnection.php');
session_start();
$r=session_id();
$statusMsg = '';
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) ){
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['id']);
    $docYorum = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['docYorum']);
    $fileName=$row["file_name"];
    $insert = $conn->query("UPDATE images SET docYorum='$docYorum' WHERE id='$id';");

 }
?>
```

Comment: this will add to your images table. for your deleting, you haven't created an interface for it yet. Is this an admin page?

Comment: at this point, if you press the submit button while the docYorum input field is empty, it will automatically empty that column in the database. If you want another implementation please specify.

Comment: thank you very much.I thought for delete it. if i set display none its gonna be invisible right?

Comment: pretty much yeah.

Comment: i added veriable to docYorum.php
$num = '';

then added this 
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
    $num = 'none';}

and added style="display:'.$num.';" to rontgenDoc.php
 but not worked can u check

Comment: what are you attempting to add none to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232787/discussion-between-hanis-hapsa-and-helen-thomas).